# Confusion with ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission and GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-api

I am carefully following [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization) about getting historical steps from Google Fit:

I've added the permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

I am checking if the user has permission like so:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      // Permission is not granted
}
```

and indeed as expected I see that the user doesn't have permission, so I am using the following code to request permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, { Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION }, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
```

This causes the following popup to appear:

[image]

Next, I want to subscribe using the recording client using this code:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(context, options)

Fitness.getRecordingClient(context, account).subscribe(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
```

But calling it throws this exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.
```

To solve this I had to call:

```
FitnessOptions options = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();

    GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(activity, GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, account, options);
```

which would show this popup:

[image]

Only then I got the steps successfully from the API.

My question is why I had to call GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions()? This isn't mentioned in the docs. I remember it was mentioned in an earlier version of the docs and then replaced with ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(). So it seems I have to call **both** functions now and not only the ActivityCompat? Maybe the docs need to be updated?

Any help on the issue would be much appriciated?

Answer (score 0):

in `ActivityCompat.requestPermission()`, you are requesting App Permissions to access a set of actions or data on the User's Device (Contacts, Messages, etc).

While `GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions()` is asking the user to allow your application to access/use a set of data inside their Google Account (photos, posts, etc).

Simple answer is, they are in no way similar or related, each one requests a completely different thing.

Comment: OK I see, so the docs are not complete. Both calls are needed. If you followed the previous version of the docs you had a complete solution. A single call to request the fit permission would show a pop to sign in with a google account and then immediately after is would show a popup to authorize access to Google Fit. This popup, by the way, is not shown any more.

Comment: The docs page you linked only speaks of requesting the Fitness permission, not that this is all you need to access Fitness data. While https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started explains that you need all 3 steps